# Very short stack trace from native crash

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libc

I'm porting a native C++ library to Android, I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
06-11 14:55:15.505: I/DEBUG(138): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-11 14:55:15.505: I/DEBUG(138): Build fingerprint: 'htc_asia_tw/htc_shooteru/shooteru:2.3.4/GRJ22/123848.4:user/release-keys'
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138): pid: 5523, tid: 5535  >>> com.xxx <<<
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0128d1a8
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  r0 0128d1a8  r1 45ba2577  r2 80808080  r3 00000000
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  r4 45ba2ba8  r5 00000005  r6 00000000  r7 45ba24e4
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  r8 45ba270c  r9 0128d1a8  10 00000001  fp 45ba2bac
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  ip 00000073  sp 45ba2478  lr afd1b64b  pc afd151e8  cpsr 60000010
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d0  65526f666e496533  d1  6143646576656934
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d2  772f73746e656d34  d3  65636170736b7235
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d4  617262657a655a2f  d5  2f696e6a2f434f50
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d6  7262657a655a7451  d7  422f6e69616d2f61
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 41d3f57724c00000
06-11 14:55:15.515: I/DEBUG(138):  d18 3ff0000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.525: I/DEBUG(138):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.525: I/DEBUG(138):  d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.525: I/DEBUG(138):  d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.525: I/DEBUG(138):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.525: I/DEBUG(138):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.525: I/DEBUG(138):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
06-11 14:55:15.525: I/DEBUG(138):  scr 20000012
06-11 14:55:15.625: I/DEBUG(138):          #00  pc 000151e8  /system/lib/libc.so
06-11 14:55:15.625: I/DEBUG(138):          #01  pc 0001b648  /system/lib/libc.so
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): code around pc:
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd151c8 0a00003d e58d2004 e59d2004 e3120003 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd151d8 1afffff6 e0800003 e3082080 e3482080 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd151e8 e4901004 e0433000 f5d0f040 e041c3a2 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd151f8 e00cc002 e1dcc001 04901004 1a000022 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd15208 e041c3a2 e00cc002 e1dcc001 04901004 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): code around lr:
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd1b628 b910c014 a018f8dd 9906e00e 0a00ebc9 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd1b638 bfa8458a e007468a f8cd4648 f7f9c014 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd1b648 f8ddeda0 4682c014 f10d2000 465c0ef8 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd1b658 f80e4683 f8cd0c01 e14cb018 46d89709 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): afd1b668 f0469f07 e00c0610 7ff00000 0002040d 
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138): stack:
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2438  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba243c  00000022  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2440  45ba27f7  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2444  afd1965f  /system/lib/libc.so
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2448  45ba270c  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba244c  45ba253c  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2450  00000082  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2454  45ba253c  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2458  00000004  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba245c  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2460  45ba24e4  
06-11 14:55:15.635: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2464  45ba270c  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2468  45ba26cd  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba246c  00000007  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2470  df002777  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2474  e3a070ad  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138): #00 45ba2478  45ba2ba8  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba247c  afd1c17d  /system/lib/libc.so
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138): #01 45ba2480  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2484  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2488  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba248c  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2490  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2494  00000073  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba2498  ffffffff  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba249c  45ba24e4  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24a0  45ba251c  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24a4  80cbce76  /data/data/com.xxx/lib/libxxx.so
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24a8  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24ac  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24b0  00000083  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24b4  45ba2577  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24b8  80cbce48  /data/data/com.xxx/lib/libxxx.so
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24bc  afd42428  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24c0  00000000  
06-11 14:55:15.645: I/DEBUG(138):     45ba24c4  00000000
```

As you can see, I have only 2 stack levels in libc.so.
After addr2line, I know it's strlen and vprintf.
I don't even get to the place where it came from in my library.

How do you get a longer stack trace than that?

(There's a possibility that the crash happens on a different thread than the one that calls the JNI functions - I don't know if it matters for that).

Comment: Why strlen would be getting a segmentation fault should be easy to imagine.  Perhaps you can think about places where that might occour.

Comment: That's exactly the purpose of the question - to AVOID thinking about places where it might occur and just have a stack trace...

Comment: Debugging doesn't work that way.  You can either exercise intelligence in interpreting the information you do have, or take measures (instrument the code, run in the debugger, re-write the crash handler) to gather more information the next time it happens.  You might even ask yourself what good vprintf() is going to do you in a GUI app, and solve that problem while you are at it.

Comment: stack may be corrupted easily so if you have stack trace shorter then you suspect it should be it is time to check the source code for 'array out of bounds' accesses to stack variables